# Why getElementsByTagName()[0] return's but getElementById()[0] return's undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

I am trying the following code and getting following results:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]); //retuns <a id="link" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"></a>

console.log($('a')[0]);//retuns <a id="link" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"></a>

console.log(document.getElementById('link'));//retuns <a id="link" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"></a>

console.log(document.getElementById('link')[0]);// returns undefined 

console.log($('#link')[0]); //retuns <a id="link" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"></a>
```

Can anybody tell why these (`console.log(document.getElementById('link')[0]);// returns undefined` and `console.log($('#link')[0]); //retuns <a id="link" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"></a>`) behave weirdly?

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/rydcX/)</kbd>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName`    (plural) returns an array.

`getElementById` (singular) returns a single element (or null).

Comment: Because there can be more than one element with same tag name, but only one element for an id.

Comment: but then why `console.log($('#link')[0]);` returns `<a id="link" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"></a>`

Comment: `$('#link')` is `$(document.getElementById('link'))`, **NOT** `document.getElementById('link')`.

Comment: @TusharGupta: All **jQuery objects** are array-like objects of zero or more elements.